# Formik onSubmit - remove form and success message

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, formik

This is the first time I'm using Formik and I'm facing the following issues:
I created this form using a typescript starter provided in the Formik documentation, and it works, but I'd like to show a success message and remove the form once axios returns with status 200.

So,
1. how do I target the form reference inside of the axios call? normally that is as simple as `e.target` but the event seems not to be available in Formik.
2. how do I access the state of the form in Formik? to toggle the success message.

The full code is available here: https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-water-ffl2w

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: ""
      }}
      // initialStatus={{ // resetForm(); resets this
      //   sent: "nope"
      // }}
      onSubmit={(
        values: Values,
        { setStatus, setSubmitting, resetForm }: FormikActions<Values>
      ) => {
        axios({
          method: "post",
          url: "https://getform.io/f/15faef97-5703-4799-930d-c3e698c99967",
          data: { email: values.email, values }
        }).then(r => {
          setSubmitting(false);
          setStatus("sent");
          //resetForm();
          console.log("Thanks!");
        });
      }}
      render={() => (
        <Form>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <Field
            id="firstName"
            name="firstName"
            placeholder="John"
            type="text"
          />

          <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <Field id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Doe" type="text" />

          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <Field
            id="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="john@acme.com"
            type="email"
          />

          <button type="submit" style={{ display: "block" }}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </Form>
      )}
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[render](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#render-props-formikpropsvalues--reactnode) is a function that gets props. I see that you use `setStatus`, so you can get `status` from `props` and make changes in Form Component

Comment: Hi Kirill, and thanks for your comment. I tried adding 'props' and 'FormikProps' to the render params `render={( { FormikProps, isSubmitting, status }) => (` and get this error: Property 'props' does not exist on type 'FormikSharedConfig & FormikState<{}> & FormikActions<{}> & FormikHandlers & FormikComputedProps<{}> & FormikRegistration'

Comment: render={({ status, isSubmitting }: FormikProps<Values>) => (/*. your Form */)}

Answer (score 4):

What I recommend is using state to control what to show in your component (for some reason I cannot save the codesandbox):

```
const BasicForm: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  const [isSent, setIsSent] = React.useState(false);
```

then, the fetch callback:

```
.then(r =>
...
    setIsSent(true);
```

Finally in your render function

```
render={({ isSubmitting, status }) =>
          !isSent ?
            <Form> ... </Form>:
            <div>Success</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an outdated version of Formik v1.1.2 and I wouldn't recommend to use it as there are some [Breaking Changes](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/migrating-v2) such as the `render` method has been **deprecated** and will be **removed** in future versions. You may want to use the current version which is **v2.1.4**

> 1. how do I target the form reference inside of the axios call?

**Formik** passes the **values** object along with other methods (called [FormikBag](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/withFormik#handlesubmit-values-values-formikbag-formikbag--void--promiseany)) inside the [onSubmit](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#onsubmit-values-values-formikbag-formikbag--void--promiseany) prop. You can pass these value directly to **axios** without the need to have your own `onSubmit` or `onChange` methods. Please note that `<Formik>` component has other [props](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#props). that will give you pretty much full control/access for your needs. That said, I'd recommend to only use Formik state/methods to avoid any side effects or bugs of having the multiple states or handlers.

**v2 General Syntax:**

```js
<Formik
   initialValues={initialValues}
   // Other Formik props...
   onSubmit = {(Object: form values, Object: Formik Bag ) => {
     // access form values...
   }}
>
 // Access render methods and props (children props)
 {(props) => {
    return (
      <Form>
        <Field> ...
      </Form>
     )
   }
 }
</Formik>
```

**axios Example:**

```js
<Formik
  initialValues={initialValues}
  onSubmit={(values) => {
    console.log(values) // Object holds your form values
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "url",
      data: { values }
    })
  })
/>
```

---

> 2. how do I access the state of the form in Formik? to toggle the success message.

You can use Formik [setStatus](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#setstatus-status-any--void) method from **FormikBag** inside your **onSubmit** to pass your server response status, then you can access that [status](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#status-any) via [children props](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#formik-render-methods-and-props) Here is an example:

```js
<Formik
  initialValues={initialValues}
  onSubmit={(values, setStatus) => {
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "url",
      data: { values }
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        // 200 means POST method response with success 
        // Pass your server response to Formik
        setStatus({
          sent: true,
          msg: "Message has been sent! Thanks!"
          // Pass more if you need
        })
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // Something went wrong
      setStatus({
        sent: false,
        msg: `Error! ${err}. Please try again later.`
      })
    })
  })
>

  // Later in your code destructuring the children props and use it like so:
  {({ status }) => ( 
    <Form>
      <Field ... />
        {status && status.msg && (
          <p className={`alert ${ status.sent ? "alert-success" : "alert-error"}`}>
            {status.msg}
          </p>
       )}
     <button>Submit</button>
    </Form>
  )}

</Formik>
```

---

I did fork your codesanbox and updated the dependencies versions/syntax in this **[codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-v2-typescript-axios-xgzmk)** Example. Please note that I'm no typescript expert.

Comment: Thank you awran5 for such a detailed and valuable answer. The sandbox returns 404, but I could follow your above examples :)